# Function that accepts function that accepts trait implementation

Tags: rust

Well the title says it all, but I'm just going to add my code as that makes it clearer what I want to do.

I have the following function:

```rust
fn calculate_rook_attacks_for(pos: &impl BoardPos, blockers: u64) -> u64 {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

I now want a higher order function that takes such calculation functions (not just this one, all functions that have this signature), but I'm struggling on the type definition. Mostly with the trait part.

I've tried:

```rust
fn generate_all_possible_attacks_for(
    calculate_moves_for: fn(impl BoardPos) -> u64
) {
    // cool generations stuff
}
```

But apparently that's not allowed:

> `impl Trait` only allowed in function and inherent method return types, not in `fn`.

I've also tried:

```rust
fn generate_all_possible_attacks_for<T>(
    calculate_attacks_for: fn(&T, u64) -> u64,
)
where
    T: BoardPos
{
    // cool generation stuff
}
```

But that complains something about type inference when trying to call it:

> cannot infer type for type parameter `T` declared on the function `generate_all_possible_attacks_for`

If I try to add the type: `::<&impl BoardPos>`, I'm back the the previous error.

I've tried various other things (also stuff with `&dyn`), but I can't remember them all.

I'm sure the resources on how to do this are out there, I just lack the correct terminology to look it up.

*(Btw, I don't want to use `&dyn` in the actual function call, as I've heard that results in a runtime performance impact)*

### Edit

Upon reading the answer I realized I'd have to specify the type at some point. I'm not sure what to do in the following case though:

```rust
fn generate_magic_number_for(pos: &impl BoardPos, piece: Piece) -> u64 {
    let idx = pos.idx();

    let (relevant_moves, number_of_relevant_moves, get_attacks_for): (
        u64,
        u64,
        fn(&impl BoardPos, u64) -> u64,
    ) = match piece {
        Piece::Bishop => (
            RELEVANT_BISHOP_MOVES_PER_SQUARE[idx],
            NUMBER_OF_RELEVANT_BISHOP_MOVES_PER_SQUARE[idx],
            piece::calculate_bishop_attacks_for,
        ),
        Piece::Rook => (
            RELEVANT_ROOK_MOVES_PER_SQUARE[idx],
            NUMBER_OF_RELEVANT_ROOK_MOVES_PER_SQUARE[idx],
            piece::calculate_rook_attacks_for,
        ),
        _ => panic!(
            "this function is only callable for bishops and rooks, was called with '{:?}'",
            piece
        ),
    };
    /// ...
}
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to cover your update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `calculate_rook_attacks_for` expands to

```
fn calculate_rook_attacks_for<T: BoardPos>(pos: &T, blockers: u64) -> u64
```

So you'd need `T` in `generate_all_possible_attacks_for`'s type to be in a different place, something like

```
fn generate_all_possible_attacks_for<F: for<T: BoardPos> Fn(&T, u64) -> u64>(
    calculate_attacks_for: F,
)
```

But this isn't legal (yet?). However, if your `generate_all_possible_attacks_for` only wants to call `calculate_attacks_for` with some specific implementation of `BoardPos`, you can just use it:

```
trait BoardPos {}

struct SomeBoardPos;
impl BoardPos for SomeBoardPos {}

fn calculate_rook_attacks_for(_pos: &impl BoardPos, _blockers: u64) -> u64 {
    0
}

fn generate_all_possible_attacks_for(
    calculate_attacks_for: impl Fn(&SomeBoardPos, u64) -> u64,
) -> u64 {
    calculate_attacks_for(&SomeBoardPos, 0)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", generate_all_possible_attacks_for(calculate_rook_attacks_for));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=trait%20BoardPos%20%7B%7D%0A%0Astruct%20SomeBoardPos%3B%0Aimpl%20BoardPos%20for%20SomeBoardPos%20%7B%7D%0A%0Afn%20calculate_rook_attacks_for(_pos%3A%20%26impl%20BoardPos%2C%20_blockers%3A%20u64)%20-%3E%20u64%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%200%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20generate_all_possible_attacks_for(%0A%20%20%20%20calculate_attacks_for%3A%20impl%20Fn(%26SomeBoardPos%2C%20u64)%20-%3E%20u64%2C%0A)%20-%3E%20u64%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20calculate_attacks_for(%26SomeBoardPos%2C%200)%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20generate_all_possible_attacks_for(calculate_rook_attacks_for))%3B%0A%7D)

Unfortunately, if you want to call `calculate_rook_attacks_for` more than once with different implementations, you'll need to pass it the same number of times (so far as I know):

```
trait BoardPos {}

struct SomeBoardPos;
impl BoardPos for SomeBoardPos {}

struct SomeBoardPos2;
impl BoardPos for SomeBoardPos2 {}

fn calculate_rook_attacks_for(_pos: &impl BoardPos, _blockers: u64) -> u64 {
    0
}

fn generate_all_possible_attacks_for(
    calculate_attacks_for: impl Fn(&SomeBoardPos, u64) -> u64,
    calculate_attacks_for2: impl Fn(&SomeBoardPos2, u64) -> u64,
) -> u64 {
    calculate_attacks_for(&SomeBoardPos, 0) + calculate_attacks_for2(&SomeBoardPos2, 0)
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", generate_all_possible_attacks_for(calculate_rook_attacks_for, calculate_rook_attacks_for));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&code=trait%20BoardPos%20%7B%7D%0A%0Astruct%20SomeBoardPos%3B%0Aimpl%20BoardPos%20for%20SomeBoardPos%20%7B%7D%0A%0Afn%20calculate_rook_attacks_for(_pos%3A%20%26impl%20BoardPos%2C%20_blockers%3A%20u64)%20-%3E%20u64%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%200%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20generate_all_possible_attacks_for(%0A%20%20%20%20calculate_attacks_for%3A%20impl%20Fn(%26SomeBoardPos%2C%20u64)%20-%3E%20u64%2C%0A)%20-%3E%20u64%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20calculate_attacks_for(%26SomeBoardPos%2C%200)%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20generate_all_possible_attacks_for(calculate_rook_attacks_for))%3B%0A%7D)

> Upon reading the answer I realized I'd have to specify the type at some point. I'm not sure what to do in the following case though:

Name the type instead of using `impl BoardPos`:

```
fn generate_magic_number_for<T: BoardPos>(pos: &T, piece: Piece) -> u64 {
    let idx = pos.idx();

    let (relevant_moves, number_of_relevant_moves, get_attacks_for): (
        u64,
        u64,
        fn(&T, u64) -> u64,
    ) = match piece {
        Piece::Bishop => (
            RELEVANT_BISHOP_MOVES_PER_SQUARE[idx],
            NUMBER_OF_RELEVANT_BISHOP_MOVES_PER_SQUARE[idx],
            piece::calculate_bishop_attacks_for,
        ),
        Piece::Rook => (
            RELEVANT_ROOK_MOVES_PER_SQUARE[idx],
            NUMBER_OF_RELEVANT_ROOK_MOVES_PER_SQUARE[idx],
            piece::calculate_rook_attacks_for,
        ),
        _ => panic!(
            "this function is only callable for bishops and rooks, was called with '{:?}'",
            piece
        ),
    };
    /// ...
}
```

Comment: Surely the whole point is to keep `generate_all_possible_attacks_for` generic?  Which one can do, provided the type is known at the call site: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=77a5cce6e7d935e1eb38ac168e306987

Comment: "Surely the whole point is to keep generate_all_possible_attacks_for generic?" It depends on the actual desired implementation. But yes, what you suggest is another possibility, probably even more likely than mine.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at this code:

```rust
trait BoardPos {}

fn calculate_rook_attacks_for(pos: &impl BoardPos, blockers: u64) -> u64 {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn generate_all_possible_attacks_for<T>(calculate_attacks_for: fn(&T, u64) -> u64)
where
    T: BoardPos,
{
    // cool generation stuff
}

fn main() {
    generate_all_possible_attacks_for(calculate_rook_attacks_for);
}
```

It makes sense that it complains about not knowing the type `T`, because neither `generate_all_possible_attacks_for` nor `calculate_rook_attacks_for` specify a type `T`. Both of them say that they need a type `T` with certain properties, but when you call the function, it needs to resolve to a concrete type that the compiler can actually compile to.

At some point, you actually need to specify what the exact type `&impl BoardPos` is supposed to be.
For example here:

```rust
trait BoardPos {}
struct MyBoardPos;
impl BoardPos for MyBoardPos {}

fn calculate_rook_attacks_for(pos: &impl BoardPos, blockers: u64) -> u64 {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn generate_all_possible_attacks_for<T>(calculate_attacks_for: fn(&T, u64) -> u64)
where
    T: BoardPos,
{
    // cool generation stuff
}

fn main() {
    generate_all_possible_attacks_for::<MyBoardPos>(calculate_rook_attacks_for);
}
```

or here:

```rust
trait BoardPos {}
struct MyBoardPos;
impl BoardPos for MyBoardPos {}

fn calculate_rook_attacks_for(pos: &impl BoardPos, blockers: u64) -> u64 {
    unimplemented!()
}

fn generate_all_possible_attacks_for(calculate_attacks_for: fn(&MyBoardPos, u64) -> u64) {
    // cool generation stuff
}

fn main() {
    generate_all_possible_attacks_for(calculate_rook_attacks_for);
}
```

---

If you want to keep the `&impl BoardPos` in the function type, to call `calculate_attacks_for` inside if `generate_all_possible_attacks_for` several times with different types, I think you are out of luck. You cannot pass a generic function into another function. At the point where you pass it into the function, it needs to be a *function pointer*. Meaning, a real function that rust actually generated as bytecode. This means all generics have to be resolved, because I don't think the concept of an abstract function pointer exists. (but of course I might be wrong, please correct me)

Comment: "You cannot pass a generic function into another function" You can, but only when it's generic over lifetimes, not types https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html

Comment: What to do if `generate_all_possible_attacks_for` receives the `pos` as `&impl BoardPos` as well? I've added something to the question.

Comment: @Elias Then you will probably have to introduce a generic: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dda58ed6a4bbf0abcae8d1935cd6debf